# HTML Button to play consecutive mp3 files

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser

I want a website with a textbox and a button next to it to play certain mp3 files back to back.

Assume I have a bunch of mp3 files in the same directory that the html file is stored.

If, in the textbox, I wrote 'hello there,' and I clicked the button next to it, the program would look for the files 'hello.mp3' and 'there.mp3', and the website would play the two files back to back.

I'm not concerned, at this point, with how the program splits up the words in the input to look for the files with those separated words, but I'm more concerned with how to play two audio files back to back with HTML.

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Play Sound from Text Input </title>
        <script>
            function play(){
                <audio>
                    <source src='hello.mp3'>
                    <source src='there.mp3'>
                </audio>
                           }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type='text'>
        <input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="play()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @styfle acknowledged, done

Answer (score 0):

Only the definition of a unique audio tag, the audio file playback, can prevent multiple audio playback pause difficult to control, unread and read the logo, play the current voice, the other audio to stop playing, voice playback is completed, automatically play next.

```js
var that, myI, myAudio = $('#audioPlayer'), otherAudio,msgid_client=0,nextAll,audioPath,audio;

this.$docChat.on('click', '.js-item .js-box-audio',function(){
    audioPlayer(this);
});
function audioPlayer(that){
    that = that,
    myI = $(that).children('.js-i'),
    audioPath = myI.attr('data-src');

    $(that).parents('.js-item').siblings('.js-item').each(function () {
        $(this).find('.js-i').removeClass('active loading');
    });

    if (myI.hasClass('active')) {
        myI.removeClass('active');
        myAudio[0].pause();
    } else {
        myI.addClass('loading');
        myAudio[0].src = audioPath;
        myAudio[0].preload="auto";
        myAudio[0].load();
    　　
        myAudio.off('loadedmetadata').on("loadedmetadata",function() {
            myI.removeClass('loading').addClass('active');
            myAudio[0].play();
        });
    }

    myAudio.off('ended').on("ended",function() {
        myI.removeClass('active');
        console.log('end');

        nextAll = $(that).parents('.js-item').nextAll();
        //console.log(nextAll);
        if(nextAll.length){
            nextAll.each(function(i,n){
                console.log(i);
                var obj  = $(n);
                if(obj.find('.js-box-audio').length){                           
                    obj.find('.js-box-audio').trigger('click',function(){ 
                        audioPlayer(this);                                                             
                    }); 
                    return false;                             
                }
            })
        }        
    })

    if($(that).hasClass('active')){
        $.ajax({
            success: function (res) {
               
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <audio src="/1.aac"></audio>
    <div class="mt20 item item-you w-100 clearfix js-item" data-id="f40a0d57-024d-4f56-b849-705e92a62eb9">
    <img class="headImg fl" src="./avatar_0.jpg">
    <div class="msg ml15 fl">
        <div class="name cl707070">
            李四
        </div>
        <div class="box box-audio  bg-clfff cl333 mt10 inblo relative js-box-audio">
            <i class="audio-i inblo js-i active" data-src="./1.aac">
            </i>
            <div style="width: 5px;max-width:3.733333rem;" class="inblo">
            </div>
            <div class="msgTime cl9b9b9b absolute">
                2"
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do I insert the audio files I want to play?

Comment: The amount of src that replaces the audio tag